# Питон выдаёт ошибку на строчке slash = SlashCommand(client,sync_commands=True)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

У меня установлены библеотеки `discord`,`discord-py-slash-command`
Из них я импортировал `CommandSlash`,`CommndContext`,`create_choice`и `create_option` но питон всё равно выдаёт ошибку
Вот весь код

```
imimportport discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_slash import SlashCommand, SlashContext 
from discord_slash.utils.manage_commands import create_choice, create_option

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents= discord.Intents.all())
slash = SlashCommand(client,sync_commands=True)
```

Код ошибки
`loop attribute cannot be accessed in non-async contexts`

Answer (score 0):

Не понял, зачем вы делаете slash? Просто перед функцией `@bot.slash_command(name='', description='')`

Comment: Старайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: @чистов_n тут больше не развернуть